# How to remove specific fields from log files before transferring using Azure Data Factory Data Flows

Tags: azure, data-science, azure-data-factory

I am new to ADF but I have managed to do some activity. My problem statement is: I have log files generated by a server, and I need to transfer them to another location for further processing. However, before transferring, I want to remove certain fields from the log files such as "partnerToken," "orgToken," and "phi_msg." I have already tested transferring the files using Azure Data Factory Copy Data, but I'm unsure how to achieve the filtering part. Should I introduce Data Flows in Azure Data Factory, and if yes, what expression can I use to drop the specified fields from the log files?

Schema:

```
    {
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "date": {
      "type": "string",
      "format": "date-time"
    },
    "level": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "msg": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "logId": {
      "type": "integer"
    },
    "traceId": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "spanId": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "resource": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "appName": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "module": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "class": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "function": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "line": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "pid": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "thread": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    },
    "attributes": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "session": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "orgToken": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "partnerToken": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "userId": {
          "type": "string"
        },  
        "phi_msg": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Any guidance on how to achieve this using Azure Data Factory Data Flows and the appropriate expression for dropping the specified fields would be highly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: what is your source and sink?

Comment: Source and Sink both are Blob Storage if that is the ask.

Comment: and file format is Json if that is important know.

Comment: please try select transformation

Comment: that sounds good. I can use select transformation to drop any column but what if I want to drop a nested object, for example "attributes" has nested object 'phi_msg'. I can drop attributes like name != 'attributes' but how to drop only phi_msg which is object of attribues?

Comment: Try parsing with selected fields and then copy it in blob

Comment: i may have to parse multiple times then because I might need to convert into an array of nested json objects or am i thinking wrong?

Answer (score 1):

To remove the fields, you need to first convert the attributes object to string and then parse it with your required field and select it.

**you can follow below steps:**

- My Json file data preview
  [image]
- Take a derived column transformation and convert the attributes object to string using expression `toString(attributes)`
  [image]
  Data preview:
  [image]
- Then parse the String attributes as below as `(session as string,     userId as string)`
  [image]
  Data preview:
  [image]
- Then in select transformation delete the `attributes` object and rename the parsed object as `attributes`
  [image]
- Store it in new file with below settings otherwise it will give you error with schema
  [image]

**Output:**
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. When I run the following Pipeline over number of files, then it reads only first line of each file and save it in the ouput.  I am putting output in the single file rather I am keeping the name to be default. I am not sure if the this information is sufficient

Comment: yes indeed the workflow works but the intention was not to store everything in one file rather in individual file. When I try to do that, it reads only first line of each file, process it and moves to another file. That part is still missing.

Comment: You posted another question for that and I answered there for processing single line.

Comment: all set thank you so much for the answers Pratik.